# Scrape multiple pages with loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup, scrape

I successfully scraped the first page of the website, but when I tried to scrape mutiples pages, it worked but the result is totally wrong.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
for num in range(1,15):
    res = requests.get('http://www.abcde.com/Part?Page={num}&s=9&type=%8172653').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".article-title"):
        print(urljoin('http://www.abcde.com',item['href']))
```

It only changed one number in every page's url, for example,

```
http://www.abcde.com/Part?Page=1&s=9&type=%8172653
http://www.abcde.com/Part?Page=2&s=9&type=%8172653
```

I got total 14 pages of this.

My code worked, but it just repeatedly print out the first page's url for 14 times. The result I expected was to print out all different urls from different pages using loops.

Comment: You're not actually formatting the string to replace the number into it... So you either need to prefix the string with `f` if you're using 3.6+ or otherwise `.format(num=num)` the string to put the page number in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jon Clements pointed, format url as below :

```
res = requests.get('http://www.abcde.com/Part?Page={}&s=9&type=%8172653'.format(num)).text
```

You can find more about python format strings at [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the info. I tried, but it said AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Sorry my bad. Missed one round bracket at last. Updated the code